# Pinging a website with discord bots in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python and I've been trying to get it to ping a website and then say if it's up or down.
Here is my code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

website = "mywebsite.com"
des = "a website status bot"
prefix = "."

client = commands.Bot(description=des, command_prefix=prefix)

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = discord.Object(id='my server id went here')
    response = 0
    while not client.is_closed:
        print("loop")    #debugger
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        global response
        pr = response
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + website)
        if response != 0:
            response = 1
        if pr != response:
            if response == 0:
                await client.send_message(channel, 'mywebsite is up!')
            else:
                await client.send_message(channel, 'mywebsite is down!')
client.run("discord-bot-code-went-here")
```

For some reason it's not running the loop. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Sidenote: The bot did work when I tryed doing a ping pong command with it so it's not the connectivity to discord also no errors came up when running the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't telling the loop to start running this task.

Inside an on_ready function, you need to add:

```
client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
```

This should start the background task, and as an added bonus for starting it in on_ready, you no longer need to wait until ready.

[Example code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py)

Comment: Thanks @squaswin, but it still doesn't seem to run the loop... I've managed to get my code working by putting it in an on_ready trigger but I'd still like it working as a background task. An idea: that code is creating a loop but is it telling the client to run it?

Comment: Could you show us your edited code in your question?

Comment: By creating the task, youre asking asyncio to run the code when it can. Since the code is being run by asyncio as a background task, then as long as the client is connected -- and the while loop doesn't throw an uncaught exception -- the client will be running it.